# Do prokaryotic chromosomes have centromeres?

Tags: chromosome

I found this [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4011006/).

> Eukaryotic chromosomes are always linear. ... In contrast, prokaryotic chromosomes are either completely devoid of centromeres or carry the so-called “plasmid centromeres” which are not essential (with a few exceptions, such as Caulobacter) (57,–60).

What does it mean by prokaryotic chromosomes carry "plasmid centromers"?
Their chromosomes carry the centromeres of plasmids? Do they have centromeres or not?

Comment: Did you look up what plasmid centromeres are? What did the references say?

Answer (score 4):

No, prokaryotes do not have centromeres.  They do, however, generally have a somewhat analogous structure used during cell division to partition the replicated chromosomes and plasmids between the two daughter cells. The analogous place on the chromosome or plasmid is the *parS* element, a DNA sequence on the chromosome or plasmid which is part of the [parABS system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ParABS_system).  This system, consisting of two proteins (*parA* and *parB*) along with *parS*, forms a [mechanism to segregate the copies of a chromosome or plasmid](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmolb.2016.00044/full#:%7E:text=Each%20system%20depends%20on%20a,which%20are%20commonly%20named%20ParB.) for the daughter cells.

*parS* is usually called a "centromere-like" site, but is sometimes referred to as a "plasmid centromere”, which is why the quote uses the phrase *so-called “plasmid centromeres”*.

Comment: Do they have a centromere-like protein that links a pair of sister chromatids?